# docker deploy error no manifest artifactory file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jar

no main manifest attribute, in app.jar

[image: Error Image]

while building pipeline job at the stage of deploy its showing like this. and also the build was successfully completed and created a container:

```
stage('Docker Deploy') {
            steps {
               script{
                    withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: 'docker-cred') 
                    {
                        sh "docker run -d --name shop-1.0 -p 8070:8070 tejash5413/webapplication-3.0"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But, the container is not running its showing:  no main manifest attribute, in app.jar.

how to resolve this error?